# Qt5 Designer and Encapsulation

Tags: c++, qt5

I've created a main window in Qt Desginer which has the following structure

- Ui_MainWindow

  - VerticalLayout

    - QTabWidget

      - Widget (*A)

        - QChart
        - QChart

The uic generates a header file "ui_mainwindow.h". This header files contains references on all the sub (subsub, subsubsub, ...) widgets. In my point of view this isn't good encapsulation.

I found a way to set custom classes for the different widgets in the Qt Designer. 
Since I have to write these classes manually I have no access/references to the child widgets. I only can control the widget itself. Still all widgets are referenced in the MainWindow UI.

Is there a way to generate separate classes for each (or some selected) widget? I'd like to intercept *A and access the child QCharts.

Thank you,

Comment: You can change the way the UI class is handled. The setting is in C++ -> Qt Class Generation, in Creator's settings. You have three choices, which are documented here: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-a-ui-file.html

Comment: Ok, I think I have a solution. I just have to implement an own hierarchy with custom classes and pass the pointer to the generated UI class to this hierarchy. Nevertheless I think it is not the best practice that the deep hierarchy in the UI XML is flattened in the generated header file.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Even though you can already "intercept A" in the current form. You can certainly separate A in a different section then add a QWidget in your main window, right click on it and promote it to being A

Comment: Do you have a concrete example? Thanks

Comment: It's difficult to give examples here where no code is involved. You can have a look at http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/designer-using-custom-widgets.html#promoting-widgets for a guided explanation